# Rotate UIWindow in iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

am creating a application which is support all type of orientation, i added one UIView on the UIWindow.but on   rotating the device the view which is added on the Window is not rotating. the view always showing default (Portrait). please help me to fix this problem ... 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a UIViewController on your UIWindow.

Answer (score 0):

UIView doesn't handle rotations, UIViewController does. 
So, all you need is to create a UIViewController, which implements shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation and sets this controller as a rootViewController to your UIWindow

Something like that:

```
    - (void) makeWindow
    {
        UIViewController * vc = [[[MyViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

        UIWindow * window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        [window setRootViewController:vc];
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }


    @interface MyViewController : UIViewController

    @end

    @implementation MyViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        //your view initialization here
    }


    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
    {
        return YES;
    }
    @end
```